# MDX,how to flatten the result of Descendants function

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-tabular

I have a hierarchy with 5 level,I use Descendants() to retrieve all lower level of a member.But i end up with a one column result where i like to have a result with one column for each level.So on each row i repeat the parent,grand parents etc of the current member.

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[key] AS 
    [DimGLAcct].[MgtCOA].CurrentMember.UNIQUENAME 
  MEMBER [Measures].[level_] AS 
    [DimGLAcct].[MgtCOA].CurrentMember.level.ordinal 
SELECT 
  { 
    [Measures].[key]
  , [Measures].[level_]
  , [Measures].[Actuals] 
  } ON COLUMNS, 
  { 
    Descendants(
      [DimGLAcct].[MgtCOA].[Mparent5].&[MCOA].&[400000M - Total operating overhead expenses].&[440000M - Other expenses].&[441000M - Other expenses]
      ,
      ,SELF_AND_AFTER
     ) 
  } ON ROWS 
FROM [Model];
```

Comment: What is the client tool? .NET code? SSRS? Can you provide a code sample so we know whether you are running ADOMD.NET code or something else?

Comment: Currently, with out some specific code and client details, this question is too broad.

Comment: The client tool is SSRS,but i am trying to get the hierarchy flatten directly in MDX.

Comment: The hierachy is Account hierarchy Level 5 to 0 ( finest detail)

Comment: L5
  L4
    L3
     L2
       L1
         L0
i am trying to get a result like that 
L5          L4           L3        L2           L1         L0      measure
A1     ALL            ALL       ALL         ALL           ALL         1000
A1     A1.1          ALL        ALL         ALL           ALL           500
A1     A1.1         A1.1.1   ALL           ALL           ALL           200
A1     A1.1       A1.1.1     A1.1.1.1     ALL          ALL           100
A1     A1.1       A1.1.1     A1.1.1.1  A1.1.1.1      ALL            50
A1     A1.1       A1.1.1     A1.1.1.1  A1.1.1.1      A1.1.1.1.1   20

Comment: The query is 
WITH
MEMBER  Measures.[key]
AS     
          [DimGLAcct].[MgtCOA].CurrentMember.UNIQUENAME
MEMBER Measures.level_ as
[DimGLAcct].[MgtCOA].CurrentMember.level.ordinal
select {
 Measures.[key],
 Measures.level_,
[Measures].[Actuals]

} on columns,
{


Descendants([DimGLAcct].[MgtCOA].[Mparent5].&[MCOA].&[400000M - Total operating overhead expenses].&[440000M - Other expenses].&[441000M - Other expenses],,SELF_AND_AFTER)

} on rows

from [Model]

Answer (score 1):

I cannot quite suss out the names of your levels but it is ok to do the following in `mdx`:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[key] AS 
    [DimGLAcct].[MgtCOA].CurrentMember.UNIQUENAME 
  MEMBER [Measures].[level_] AS 
    [DimGLAcct].[MgtCOA].CurrentMember.level.ordinal 
SELECT 
  { 
    [Measures].[key]
  , [Measures].[level_]
  , [Measures].[Actuals] 
  } ON COLUMNS, 

  [DimGLAcct].[LevelX]
 *[DimGLAcct].[LevelY]
 *[DimGLAcct].[LevelZ]
 *[DimGLAcct].[LevelK]

   ON ROWS 
FROM [Model];
```

Each of the levels in your user hierarchy will have respective attribute hieraries - which are used in the above.

Comment: Hi,yes that was my first thought and it's another query i do use however my global problem is a bit more complicated because i need to stack multiple time all descendant of members in rows. So i will have a first set of all the descendants of member A1 then under all the descendants of member B2. So when i use the cross join approach i can't do that ( even when i use join ).The usual way to do that is to use hierarchize and union but i end up with everything in one column.

Vincent